# RegEx not matching string in production, however works on tester

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string: `/v0/lifts/0626df905120f6d6/refs/8f23576e6838b528`. I'm trying to get the third URL string, so wrote the following RegEx: `/([^/]*)\w+/g`. According to Regexr, this should [match all parts of the URL](http://www.regexr.com/39r90).

Then, with Javascript I tried to access the third array element:

```
var key = /([^/]*)\w+/g.exec('/v0/lifts/0626df905120f6d6/refs/8f23576e6838b528')[2];
```

However, this comes as undefined. If you print the result of it (as JSON), you get `["v0","v"]`.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You'd have to call `.exec` three times to get the third match: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Example.3A_Finding_successive_matches

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that is wrong is using the wrong tool for the job.

Just split on `/`, you dont need regular expressions.

```
'/v0/lifts/0626df905120f6d6/refs/8f23576e6838b528'.split('/')[3]; //0626df905120f6d6
```

Now, if you do want to use a regex, use `match` instead:

```
'/v0/lifts/0626df905120f6d6/refs/8f23576e6838b528'.match(/([^/]*)\w+/g) //["v0", "lifts", "0626df905120f6d6", "refs", "8f23576e6838b528"]
```

`exec` is only useful when you have multiple capturing groups per match.

Comment: The simpler regexps `/\w+/g` or `/[^/]+/g` would serve just as well. But I agree that `split` is a better fit for this problem, especially if you have empty parts (e.g. /foo//bar/baz).